# django error when upload image in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, python-imaging-library

When i try upload image in admin panel i get message:

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

```
#models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img2')
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

[Traceback](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GpBJ5Qc4)
How fix this? Thanks :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `MEDIA_ROOT` set as a tuple, not a string.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are declaring this as a tuple:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/'),)
```

See the `,)` at the end? This way should be better:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')
```

Hope it helps.